# Taking ownership over processes

Tags: windows-10, permissions, process, ownership

Whatever I write on google I get only results on how to change ownership over **files and folders**. I KNOW IT! I need to change the ownership over a **PROCESS**. Okay, enough shouting. I tried it using Process Explorer or Process Hacker, but without success. The process I want to steal is named **"sppsvc.exe"**. When I try to take ownership it tells me:

> Unable to set new owner on "sppsvc.exe"
>
> Access is denied.

Or:

> "unable to save permission changes"

Anyways, It doesn't allow me that.

My goal is to permanetly suspend it. I don't know how to do it either, so I decided to experiment in those programs (Process Explorer and Process Hacker).
I noticed I can't change anything (Affinity, Priority, ... anything) because I am not the owner.

Comment: I mean to suspend the process. Reason: sppsvc.exe is consuming lot of CPU, so I want to get rid of it. when I stop it I can't use office. But I found that if I suspend the process, CPU is idle and I can use Office, but then, I need to suspend it every time I reboot the system (which is annoying)

Comment: The security may be lie in the registry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sppsvc`.

Comment: Stop that service with command::`sc stop sppsvc`

Answer (score 1):

OK, dudilies, here is the trick (it's not like it's already in comments...):

1. You go to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sppsvc`
2. You raise your blood pressure
3. delete `Security\Security` (maybe? ...I did anyway)
4. set LaunchProtected to `0`
5. Restart your machine

NOTE: don't save a backup of the registry